# Compare two std::vector<cv::Point> vectors and safe common points to a third std::vector<cv::Point>

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I'm looking for an alternative version for the `std::set_intersection` function but for `std::vector<cv::Point>` vectors.

I try to compare two `std::vector<cv::Point>` vectors with different sizes. Those  two contain coordinate lists. The main task of the intersection-like Method should now be to detect common pairs and safe them to a third `std::vector<cv::Point>` via `push_back()`

I searched for a function like `std::set_intersection(v1.begin(),v1.end(),v2.begin(),v2.end(),back_inserter(v3));`

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) does exactly this, what's the problem? `v1` and `v2` must be sorted.

Comment: I sorted my vectors before, but I get an error C2893: failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::less<void>::operator()(_Ty1 &&,Ty2 && const'.(from file algorithm). The vectors i use contain x and y coordinates.`std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
 std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
 std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), back_inserter(v3));`

Comment: @Flippy Use a custom comparision for `std::sort`, i.e. `std::sort(v1.begin(), v2.end(), [](cv::Point lhs, cv::Point rhs){ return (lhs.x < rhs.x || (lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y <= rhs.y));}`

Comment: And then the same custom comparator for `std::set_intersection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by @BoBTFish and @NaCl, you need to use a *custom comparator*, and apply `set_intersection` on *sorted* vectors.

Since you need to call the comparator three times, it's useful to use a function instead of a lambda expression.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

// Custom less comparator
bool lessPoints(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
    return (lhs.x < rhs.x) || ((lhs.x == rhs.x) && (lhs.y < rhs.y));
}

vector<Point> intersection(vector<Point> v1, vector<Point> v2)
{
    vector<Point> v3;
    // Sort vectors
    sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(), lessPoints);
    sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(), lessPoints);
    // Intersect
    set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), back_inserter(v3), lessPoints);
    return v3;
}

int main()
{
    // Your vectors
    vector<Point> v1{ Point(2,3), Point(1,2), Point(5,5), Point(3,4) };
    vector<Point> v2{ Point(2,1), Point(1,2), Point(3,4), Point(6,7), Point(0,3) };

    // Find intersections
    vector<Point> v3 = intersection(v1, v2);

    // Print out vector content
    std::copy(v3.begin(), v3.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Point>(std::cout, " "));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, great help, made a similar intersection method made from the comments above, but now it works!